# Excel 2013 - Pivot Table - Add all fields as Values

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I would like to add every field that I select as a **value** (instead they are automatically added as rows) and as a **product** (they are automatically a count).

This would save me a massive amount of time. So far I have not found any default add options.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a problem with Excel for a long time.  The solution to your first problem is to drag the fields into the value field box under the field list.

There is no way to change the default summary operation, but the reason you're getting COUNT is that there are some cells in the data that contain non-numeric values (otherwise you'd get SUM.)

The only solution I've seen for this is to program your own pivot table builder in VBA or write a macro that automatically updates all fields in the table to a certain operation after they are added.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That really sucks to hear though, this just went from being a few hours to a few days.

Comment: I understand.  If you search you can probably find an add-in that can help, but I haven't tested any of them.

Comment: To expand on @jbarker2160's answer (+1, BTW :) ), if I were you, I'd look into writing a quick macro - It's easier than you think

Answer (score 1):

To convert from count to Sum, i found the below works for me.

1. Click any cell in your pivot table.
2. Hold down the ALT + F11 keys, and it opens the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications window.
3. Click Insert > Module, and paste the following code in the Module Window.

VBA code: Change multiple field settings in pivot table

```vb
Public Sub SetDataFieldsToSum()
    'Update 20141127
    Dim xPF As PivotField
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    With WorkRng.PivotTable
       .ManualUpdate = True
       For Each xPF In .DataFields
          With xPF
             .Function = xlSum
             .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
          End With
       Next
       .ManualUpdate = False
    End With
End Sub
```

4. Then press F5 key to execute this code, and all the field settings in your selected pivot table have been converted to your need calculation at once